# Correlation functions and non-bravais lattices

Tags: symmetry, many-body, greens-functions

Consider a many-body system characterized by some Green's function $G(\vec{x},\vec{x}',t)$. In the presence of translation invariance, it's natural to work with the Fourier transform of this:

$$G(\vec{k},\omega) = \int d\omega d\vec{k} \exp\left[i\left(\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x}-\omega t\right)\right]G(\vec{x},t)$$

The extension of this idea to a lattice model is obvious if there is a single atom in the basis - just change integrals to sums, where the translation invariance is now by Bravais lattice vectors. Then $G(\vec{x},\vec{x}',t) = G(|\vec{x}-\vec{x}'|,t)$, like usual. But if we have a non-Bravais lattice, i.e., multiple sites in the lattice basis, what is the natural generalization of this idea?

Something I can think of is to label the atoms in the basis by Greek indices; this restores the translation invariance for each correlator, so that we can have a matrix of correlation functions $G^{\alpha\beta}(|\vec{x}-\vec{x}'|,t)$. 
What I'm struggling to understand is what we can do with this object? Diagonalizing this matrix of correlators should not generally give you a translation-invariant object and does not have a simple relation to a Green's function that I can see. So what's the sensible way to think about  correlators in this context?